# Is there a way to change PHP files automatically?

Tags: php

Is there a way that something can be written with PHP that will make changes to a PHP file?

For example, if I wanted to modify a script (whether it be simply adding a small feature or changing an existing feature), instead of posting a tutorial with a bunch of "Find this:", "Replace with this:" or "Find this:", "After, add this:", could I write a PHP page or something that makes these changes for the user with a simple click?

Comment: Absolutely. Writing a PHP file is no different than writing any other file with PHP.

Comment: You could write an update mechanism that replaces old files with your new version or you could patch files. Then you have to look for certain patterns in the file content in order to create a secure update/patch procedure. But the file permissions must but be sufficient to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just load the file to a variable (as long as your server user has access to write to the file), and alter the variable, then overwrite the file.

```
$content = file_get_contents('test.php');
$content = preg_replace('/find/', 'replace', $content);
file_put_contents('test.php', $content);
//if you need to append to the file, use this flag
//warning: the default (no flag) in third parameter is to overwrite the entire file.
file_put_contents('test.php', $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

It's just like editing any other file.
If you need to loop through the lines, this function is more useful:

```
$content = file('test.php');
$result  = '';
foreach($content as $line) {
    if(preg_match('/find/', $line) {
        $result .= $replacement;
    } else {
        $result .= $line;
    }
}
file_put_contents('test.php', $result);
```

This is just an example, since I don't know exactly how you need to replace things in the file.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this would be to add contents to a file (looks like it would just add it to the end of the file?), but how would I use this to find a line inside a php file, and replace it with something else... modifying the contents of the file rather than adding to it?

Comment: That depends on how you need to replace things. You can do it just by editing the content variable.

Comment: I've tried using str_replace but it throws errors when I try to find an entire line, and the replace it with another.

Answer (score -1):

U check about git? git push and and git pull, maybe its yout solutions... whit 2 click (if u work with Graphics Interfaces) or 2 comands (if you use a terminal)

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Comment: OP means automatically, I think. With a php script. Although, I think git has a php api, which would make a pretty useful way of doing it.